# Jinja if statement not execute properly

Tags: flask

I'm using Jinja + Flask

Here's the example code:

```
# Flask
@app.route('/test/<int:counter>'):
    return render_templates('test.html', counter)

# Jinja
## test.html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% if counter|int == 1 %}
{% block scoreboard1 %}active1{% endblock %}
{% elif counter|int == 2 %}
{% block scoreboard2 %}active2{% endblock %}
{% elif counter|int == 3 %}
{% block scoreboard3 %}active3{% endblock %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}

## layout.html
<a href="/scoreboard/1" class="{% block scoreboard1 %}{% endblock %} item">1</a>
<a href="/scoreboard/2" class="{% block scoreboard2 %}{% endblock %} item">2</a>
<a href="/scoreboard/3" class="{% block scoreboard3 %}{% endblock %} item">3</a>
```

Here's the result (inspect in chrome dev tool):

```
# URL -> 127.0.0.1/test/2
<a href="/scoreboard/1" class="active1 item">1</a>
<a href="/scoreboard/2" class="active2 item">2</a>
<a href="/scoreboard/3" class="active3 item">3</a>
```

Expecting result:

```
# URL -> 127.0.0.1/test/2
<a href="/scoreboard/1" class=" item">1</a>
<a href="/scoreboard/2" class="active2 item">2</a>
<a href="/scoreboard/3" class=" item">3</a>
```

I'm expecting block will depends on the counter value, but instead, it changes it all.

I'm kind of curious what cause this bug triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `block` in a conditional like this, no matter if the condition is met or not, as soon as you the `block` is in your child template, it will be filled.

There are a couple of ways to achieve (what I'm assuming is) what you want, for example you could use a [macro](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#macros):

```
{% macro scoreboardlink(counter) %}
    <a href="/scoreboard/1" class="{% if counter|int == 1 %}active1{% endif %} item">1</a>
    <!-- you should look into url_for() instead of hardcoding your urls -->
    ...
{%- endmacro %}
```

You'd then use this in your template like this:

```
...
{{ scoreboardlink(counter) }}
...
```

But, if you want the structure `layout.html` as you have it, you can of course just slightly adjust and put the conditional inside your blocks:

```
{% block scoreboard1 %}
    {% if counter|int == 1 %}active1{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This solved my problem :)).
Just found how how dumb I am :P